# Show limit is meaningless

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x$ not equal to $0$, $f(0)=0$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x \in \mathbb R$.  I would like to show that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{g(f(x))-g(f(0))}{f(x)-f(0)}$$

is meaningless.

If I let $h(x) = \frac{g(f(x))-g(f(0))}{f(x)-f(0)}$, I know that for $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}h(x)$ to be meaningful, $h$ needs to be defined on $J$ \ $\{0\}$ for some open interval $J$.

But I do not know how to proceed from here.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $h$ is when $x, \sin(1/x) \neq 0$, or equivalently:
$$
D = \{x \in \mathbb R \mid x \neq 0 \text{ and } x \neq \tfrac{1}{n\pi} \text{ for all } n \in \mathbb Z\}
$$
We claim that there is no punctured neighbourhood of the form $(-a, 0) \cup (0, b) \subseteq D$, where $a, b > 0$. Indeed, suppose towards a contradiction that such a punctured neighbourhood did exist. By the Archimedean property of the reals, notice that there exists some $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $m > \frac{1}{b\pi}$. Hence, since $0 < \frac{1}{m\pi} < b$, it follows that:
$$
\frac{1}{m\pi} \in (-a, 0) \cup (0, b)
$$
but
$$
\frac{1}{m\pi} \notin D
$$
a contradiction. So no such punctured neighbourhood exists, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$